# Including template files in Go executable

Tags: go

I want to parse a folder of template HTML files and cache (or buffer) them on build for later use in a web project. Basically I am trying to make it so when I build my project I dont need to take the HTML files with me when I upload the executable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you are talking about embedding the html files in your binary?

If so the best way to do this that I've seen so far has been camlistores fileembed: https://code.google.com/p/camlistore/source/browse/pkg/fileembed/fileembed.go

See here for directions on use: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/LQMv7Zsmsi0/8Aax1XSekjAJ

That thread has addtional info on other packages for this as well.

Comment: Thanks. I realized what i originally asked wont particularly work for me cause if i start down this road i then have to do other files such as css, js and images. But still good to know, thanks.

Comment: actually I use fileembed to embed all those things and it's pretty good. You keep them in the directory structure as usual and genfileembed does all the work. You even use the embedded files just like a regular file system and you can set it to dev mode so you can use the files from desk when you are iterating.

Comment: Do you have usage examples of how you have used this?

Comment: Not in a public repo at the moment. but if you look in camlistores repos you will see a number of examples: https://code.google.com/p/camlistore/source/browse/#git%2Fserver%2Fcamlistored%2Fui